# Amazon cloudsearch: Fuzzy search by field with boto3

Tags: lucene, boto3, amazon-cloudsearch

How can do fuzzy search in Amazon Cloudsearch by field?

I tried it. But it's not works

```py
cloudsearch.search(
    query="1976~100",
    queryParser='simple',
    partial=True,
    # queryOptions='{"fields":["passport_number"]}',
    queryOptions='{"operators":["fuzzy"],"fields":["passport_number"]}',
    returnFields="cognito_id,pk"
)
```

Also I tried this

```py
cloudsearch.search(
    query="(near field=passport_number '1976')",
    queryParser='structured',
    partial=True,
    returnFields="cognito_id,pk"
)
```

But this not works also.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `lucene` as `query parser` along with [`wildcards`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-WildcardSearches)

```
cloudsearch.search(
    query='passport_number:*1976*',
    queryParser='lucene',
    partial=True,
    returnFields="cognito_id,pk"
)
```